# ¿Cómo conectar laravel a MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy empezando a utilizar Laravel para un proyecto que tengo entre manos y me está gustando bastante aunque hay que aprender a usarlo antes.

Mi archivo dentro de `mi_proyecto_laravel/config/database.php` es este:

http://pastebin.com/sBSqwQ7s

En la sección del `mysql` le he puesto los datos de mi base de datos y luego he intentado hacer esta consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$res = $db->query($sql) OR DIE ("Erro sql: ".$sql);
while($row = $res -> fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['nombre'];
}
```

Pero me ha salido una página llena de errores. Me imagino que es porque laravel tiene sus propios "métodos" para acceder a las bases de datos pero, la verdad es que lo desconozco y no sé como acceder a la mía en este caso.

Gracias.

Comment: Sí, esas consultas que colocas no se deberían de utilizar, Laravel permite realizar todo eso con el ORM te recomiedo revisar la documentación oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent . Con respecto a la configuración de la base de datos, configurastes el archivo .env que está en el directorio principal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Tus datos de la base de datos deben estar en el archivo `.env` que se encuenta en la raíz del proyecto:

   ```
   DB_DATABASE=...
   DB_USERNAME=...
   DB_PASSWORD=...
   .... (los demás parámetros)
   ```
2. Idealmente deberías tener un modelo para esa tabla usuarios, dicho modelo probablemente ya existe en el proyecto y está en app/User.php
3. Una vez tengas el modelo será muy sencillo acceder a sus propiedades y a sus relaciones, entre otras, con Eloquent.

   El ejemplo rápido para lo que quieres hacer en esa consulta sería:

   ```
   $users = User::all(); // probablemente este código vay en un controlador
   ```

   En la vista tendrías algo así, gracias a Blade:

   ```
   @foreach ($users as $user)
       {{ $user->name }}
   @endforeach
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes un video sobre el tema, tambien hay otros videos que explican cada uno de los componentes del framework. [Base de datos en Laravel](https://styde.net/migraciones-seeders-y-model-factories/)

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow es! Un simple enlace a un vidéo o documentación no se entiende como una respuesta valida aquí, ya por la razón que la fuente externa eventualmente puede ya no ser disponible. Puedes agregar una solución más concreta a tu publicación?